# .htaccess Rewrite; but Variable needed

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Hello Stackers,**

I Currently have a Problem with my HTACCESS file. It needs to rewrite a Url, which it does, but I still need a Variable to pass through.

```
RewriteRule ^ref/(.*)$ /quickregister/start.php?ref=$1
```

The Link used is `example.com/ref/value` however, after the rewrite, no variables are recognizable, but I need the value of the REF variable.

Is there A way to do this? Also, I would preffer to still get `if(isset($_GET['ref'])){` working.

Comment: Your rule is working on my server.

Comment: Define _not working_! How is it not working? What is the desired result/rewirte/url and what are you actually getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my standard .htaccess file which I use for all of my rewrite websites...

```
## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects


RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Using this file everything in the URL if it is not a valid directory or file is ignored and routed to index.php in the site root. I then access it as a single paramater using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which I can explode using `explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`, this gives me an array starting at index 0 of each value. Using this script I am still able to access $_GET variables as long as at the end of the URI the convention `?var_name=value` has been used.

This has been tested and works with Apache, PHP5 and works both debian based linux operating systems as well as Windows installs of Apache.